# When is this indefinite integral $\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^n+1}}$ expressible in terms of elliptic integrals?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

Excluding the elementary trivial cases $n=1,2$, I know that for $n=3,4,6,8,12,20$, this integral can be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals, as shown below.

$$
\begin{aligned}
{\cal I}_3&=2\wp^{-1}(x;0,-4)\\
{\cal I}_4&=\wp^{-1}(x^2;-4,0)\\
{\cal I}_6&=-\wp^{-1}\left(\frac1{x^2};0,-4\right)\\
{\cal I}_8&=-\frac12\wp^{-1}\left(x^2+\frac1{x^2}+\frac23;\frac{40}3,\frac{224}{27}\right)+\frac12\wp^{-1}\left(x^2+\frac1{x^2}-\frac23;\frac{40}3,-\frac{224}{27}\right)\\
{\cal I}_{12}&=-\frac\zeta{\sqrt3}\wp^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2}\zeta+\frac\zeta{x^2};12,0\right)+\frac{\zeta^5}{\sqrt3}\wp^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2}{\zeta^5}+\frac{\zeta^5}{x^2};12,0\right),\quad\color{blue}{\zeta={\rm e}^{\frac{2\pi{\rm i}}6}}\\
{\cal I}_{20}&=\frac{\zeta^3}{\sqrt2\sqrt[8]{5^3}\sqrt{1+\sqrt5}}\wp^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{x^2}{\zeta^4}+\frac{\zeta^4}{x^2}}{\sqrt[4]5}+\frac{\sqrt[4]5}{\frac{x^2}{\zeta^4}+\frac{\zeta^4}{x^2}}+\frac23;\frac{4(10+3\sqrt5)}3,\frac{16(14+9\sqrt5)}{27}\right)\\&\quad
+\frac{\zeta^3}{\sqrt2\sqrt[8]{5^3}\sqrt{1+\sqrt5}}\wp^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{x^2}{\zeta^4}+\frac{\zeta^4}{x^2}}{\sqrt[4]5}+\frac{\sqrt[4]5}{\frac{x^2}{\zeta^4}+\frac{\zeta^4}{x^2}}-\frac23;\frac{4(10+3\sqrt5)}3,\frac{16(14+9\sqrt5)}{27}\right)\\&\quad
-\frac{\zeta^3}{\sqrt2\sqrt[8]{5^3}\sqrt{1+\sqrt5}}\wp^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{x^2}{\zeta^{16}}+\frac{\zeta^{16}}{x^2}}{\sqrt[4]5}+\frac{\sqrt[4]5}{\frac{x^2}{\zeta^{16}}+\frac{\zeta^{16}}{x^2}}+\frac23;\frac{4(10+3\sqrt5)}3,-\frac{16(14+9\sqrt5)}{27}\right)\\&\quad
-\frac{\zeta^3}{\sqrt2\sqrt[8]{5^3}\sqrt{1+\sqrt5}}\wp^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{x^2}{\zeta^{16}}+\frac{\zeta^{16}}{x^2}}{\sqrt[4]5}+\frac{\sqrt[4]5}{\frac{x^2}{\zeta^{16}}+\frac{\zeta^{16}}{x^2}}-\frac23;\frac{4(10+3\sqrt5)}3,-\frac{16(14+9\sqrt5)}{27}\right),\\&\quad
\quad\color{blue}{\zeta={\rm e}^{\frac{2\pi{\rm i}}{20}}}
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\wp^{-1}(z;g_2,g_3)$ denotes the inverse Weierstrass elliptic function.

Comment: How did you find $\mathcal I_8$ and so on?

Comment: I found them by trying a substitution $t=\frac{x^n}k+\frac k{x^n}$. But it doesn’t work for other n values.

Comment: I guess $\mathcal I_{24}$ might be expressible in terms of elliptic integrals since $K[(2-\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})]=C\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{24}+1}}\mathrm dx$ where $C$ is an algebraic number.

Comment: First one is easy. $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+1}}=\int\frac{2dx}{\sqrt{4x^3+4}}$. You see, $,g_2=0, g_3=-4.$